# Pandas wide_to_long with random id variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some trouble with the wide_to_long function. This example works fine:

```
Loc   Nom   Meas-1   Meas-2   Meas-3
200   A     0.8      1.1      1.2
201   B     4.9      5.1      5.2

pd.wide_to_long(df, 'Meas', i=['Loc','Nom'], j='Ref', sep='-').reset_index()

Loc   Nom   Meas   Ref
200   A     0.8    1
200   A     1.1    2
200   A     1.2    3
201   B     4.9    1
201   B     5.1    2
201   B     5.2    3
```

My problem is that the string that follows "Meas-" in my dataframe is a random, alpha-numeric serial number. A basic example:

```
Loc   Nom   Meas-1   Meas-2D   Meas-3
200   A     0.8      1.1       1.2
201   B     4.9      5.1       5.2

pd.wide_to_long(df, 'Meas', i=['Loc','Nom'], j='Ref', sep='-').reset_index()

Loc   Nom   Meas   Meas-2D   Ref
200   A     0.8    1.1       1
200   A     1.2    1.1       3
201   B     4.9    5.1       1
201   B     5.2    5.1       3
```

Worse, if all of the "Meas-" parts are followed by strings containing letters, I get an empty dataframe error:

```
Loc   Nom   Meas-1D   Meas-2D   Meas-3D
200   A     0.8       1.1       1.2
201   B     4.9       5.1       5.2

pd.wide_to_long(df, 'Meas', i=['Loc','Nom'], j='Ref', sep='-').reset_index()

Empty DataFrame
```

How can I get this function to use whatever string follows "Meas-" for Ref, and not only numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried to add a table in here, but it didn't work. Please disregard this reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `suffix` parameter.(If you do not mention it , it will default looking for number `'\d+'` , since '2D' is not number , then return nothing)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, 'Meas', i=['Loc','Nom'], j='Ref', sep='-',suffix='\w+').reset_index()
Out[289]: 
   Loc Nom Ref  Meas
0  200   A   1   0.8
1  200   A  2D   1.1
2  200   A   3   1.2
3  201   B   1   4.9
4  201   B  2D   5.1
5  201   B   3   5.2
```

Comment: :)  A question about pd.wide_to_long?    +1

Comment: I don't know how you always answer my questions before I could get a cup of coffee, but this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottBoston thank you man (really hope they can make the official document more clear:-))

Comment: @AndrewWinter I used to have the same problem . :-)

Comment: @AndrewWinter Hi, man if this is what you need would you like accept it ?

Comment: @Wen, you're too quick. It wouldn't let me accept the answer until the question had been submitted for ten minutes and you had me on my way within 1 minute haha. Accepted now, thanks again!

Comment: @AndrewWinter yw :-) haha , have a nice day